# unit testing vuetify component v-checkbox

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to test v-checkbox component.
Calling once trigger click will change the checkbox status checked.

```
  const flag = wrapper.find('.input-group--selection-controls__ripple')[0]
  flag.trigger('click')
```

Calling twice trigger click will not change checkbox status unchecked.
How to implement?

```
  const flag = wrapper.find('.input-group--selection-controls__ripple')[0]
  flag.trigger('click')
  flag.trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get my test to work I also had to find the specific element below, but I did not need flushPromises().  Finding the right element with the class="input-group--selection-controls__ripple" was the key using the class selector below.  That allowed the click event to update the binding I was trying to test.  Simply finding the

```
<v-checkbox class-"my-checkbox"/>
```

was not correct, as the click event didn't work on that element.

```
it('Does uncheck', async() => {
    // We need to drill down to the .input-group--selection-controls__ripple element so the click works
    const myCheckbox = wrapper.find('.my-checkbox').find('.input-group--selection-controls__ripple');
    myCheckbox.trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.someField).toEqual(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
// If data is loaded asynchronously, use flush-promises to wait for the data to load.
await flushPromises()
 // Find the delete button for the first to-do item and trigger a click event on it.
$emit('.input-group--selection-controls__ripple', event.target.checked)
```

Check out the [Vue Test Utils guide](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#getting-started) and specifically the [async behavior](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-asynchronous-behavior). Additionally, [A gentle introduction to testing Vue applications](https://dev.to/bahdcoder_47/a-gentle-introduction-to-testing-vue-applications-52jk) is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//in the component
<v-checkbox data-test="select-number"/>

//in the test use this 
const selectInput = wrapper.get('[data-test="select-number"]')
expect(selectInput.vnode.elm.checked).toBe(true)
```